# How to change background color in Django Admin Dashboard

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Please tell me how to change background color in django admin dashboard. And maybe all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a step by step blog which guides you in changing the background color of the admin panel.
[DJANGO ADMIN PANEL BG Color change blog](https://www.dothedev.com/blog/django-admin-change-color/)

below is the official documentation regarding the admin site and the customization options

[DJANGO ADMIN DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/)